# Toggle one div at a time in mobile view

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, jsfiddle

I have a footer that displays as an accordion menu on mobile devices only. Therefore, the `ul` elements must be hidden on load only on mobile devices. Only one of the sections should open at a time, and if there is one already open, it will close when another is triggered (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/auUxk/). I have the code below, but it is currently triggering the divs globally.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">About us</h4>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Header</h4>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MEDIA QUERY**

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  ul li{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".panel-title").click(function() {
        $("li").slideToggle(500); 
    });
});
```

**JSFIDDLE**:http://jsfiddle.net/auUxk/1115/

Answer (score 3):

Why you don't use only css? 
With radio buttons with the same name will work.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/0Ldpk0vy

Updated (with animation) JSFIDDLE: [http://jsfiddle.net/0Ldpk0vy/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/0Ldpk0vy/1)

```
ul {
  display: none;
}

[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Because this can and should be done with a list. Care to post a fiddle with radio buttons?

Comment: You need the behavior of the radio buttons but you have to hide that.
Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0Ldpk0vy/

Comment: This should be accomplished with jQuery, not adding radio buttons to the markup.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? why should I prefer a javascript solution instead of a css only solution (with a little more markup but more perfomance)?

Comment: It has the same behavior. Why should I prefer that solution?

Comment: I would prefer to do this with jQuery. Also, the sections need to be able to not only open one and close another, but also close itself when clicked. Plus, the content should slide up/down.

Comment: The updated jsfiddle have already slide animation. If you need to close itself if closed you need js. But you can use only a simple line of js to uncheck the radio button when the radio button is checked.